# Bundler error when running compass

Tags: rvm, bundler, compass-sass

When running

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247    
compass create . --bare --sass-dir "css" --css-dir "css" --javascripts-dir "js" --images-dir "img"
```

in a directory containing only html and css files I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:361:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.12/bin/compass:26:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass:23:in `load'
from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

This does not make sense to me, because there is not even a Gemfile present.

My questions:

- What Gemfile could this message be refering to?
- How can I make this run? I feel that creating a Gemfile because of that should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird, but the reason seems to be that there was a Gemfile in my **home dir**.
Removing it made this error go away.